# Two Colliders overlap a little bit each other in Unity

Tags: unity-game-engine

After coding left and right movement of player which had BoxCollider and Rigidbody, An serious problem happened. when player moved toward an cube which had BoxCollider, player's collider overlapped with the cube by 0.02. Please tell me how to fix this problem.

For your information, the movement that I made was by rigidbody.MovePosition in FixedUpdate. And I already set collision detection to continuous. Also, I set the friction to zero with Physics Material.

When player don't move, the x Position is 2.525 [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8Aqs3.png)

But when player move, the x Position is 2.545 [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/D5OmC.png)

Answer (score 0):

Colliders overlap - it's how collision detection works. If the overlap is too great, you can make one or both of them bigger, make the physics settings tighter, or some combination of these. Note that the amount of overlap is also affected by the speed of the objects - the more speed, the more potential overlap. What you can't do is expect PhysX to work with no collider overlap.